# Java 8 Stream API to find Unique Object matching a property value

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

Find the object matching with a Property value from a Collection using Java 8 Stream.

```
List<Person> objects = new ArrayList<>();
```

Person attributes -> Name, Phone, Email.

Iterate through list of Persons and find object matching email. 
Saw that this can be done through Java 8 stream easily. But that will still return a collection?

Ex:

```
List<Person> matchingObjects = objects.stream.
    filter(p -> p.email().equals("testemail")).
    collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I know that it will always have one unique object. Can we do something instead of `Collectors.toList` so that i got the actual object directly.Instead of getting the list of objects.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Instead of using a collector try using `findFirst` or `findAny`.

```
Optional<Person> matchingObject = objects.stream().
    filter(p -> p.email().equals("testemail")).
    findFirst();
```

This returns an `Optional` since the list might not contain that object.

If you're sure that the list always contains that person you can call:

```
Person person = matchingObject.get();
```

**Be careful though!** `get` throws `NoSuchElementException` if no value is present. Therefore it is strongly advised that you first ensure that the value is present (either with `isPresent` or better, use `ifPresent`, `map`, `orElse` or any of the other alternatives found in the `Optional` class).

If you're okay with a `null` reference if there is no such person, then:

```
Person person = matchingObject.orElse(null);
```

If possible, I would try to avoid going with the `null` reference route though. Other alternatives methods in the Optional class (`ifPresent`, `map` etc) can solve many use cases. Where I have found myself using `orElse(null)` is only when I have existing code that was designed to accept `null` references in some cases.

---

Optionals have other useful methods as well. Take a look at [Optional javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: Although I would recommend against using orElse(null) where possible.

Comment: what is p here?

Comment: The `filter` method on a stream accepts a lambda expression that is applied to each stream element. `p` is the argument for the lambda expression. Since `objects` is of type `List<Person>`, `p` in that case is a `Person`.

Comment: @HariKiran`p` is the current person object that filter applies on it

Answer (score 39):

## `findAny` & `orElse`

By using [`findAny()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) and [`orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-):

```
Person matchingObject = objects.stream().
filter(p -> p.email().equals("testemail")).
findAny().orElse(null);
```

Stops looking after finding an occurrence.

> `findAny`
>
> `Optional<T> findAny()`
>
> Returns an Optional describing some element of the stream, or an empty Optional if the stream is empty.
> This is a short-circuiting terminal operation.
> The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic; it is free to select any element in the stream. This is to allow for maximal performance in parallel operations; the cost is that multiple invocations on the same source may not return the same result. (If a stable result is desired, use findFirst() instead.)

Answer (score 12):

Guava API provides [MoreCollectors.onlyElement(](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MoreCollectors.html#onlyElement--)) which is a collector that takes a **stream containing exactly one element** and **returns that element**.

The returned collector **throws** an `IllegalArgumentException` if the stream **consists of two or more elements**, and a `NoSuchElementException` if the **stream is empty**.

Refer the below code for usage:

```
import static com.google.common.collect.MoreCollectors.onlyElement;

Person matchingPerson = objects.stream
                        .filter(p -> p.email().equals("testemail"))
                        .collect(onlyElement());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method .reduce() instead .get() or .orElseGet().
That will help you to avoid `NoSuchElementException` and `NullPointerException`

```
Person matchingObject = objects.stream()
.filter(p -> p.email().equals("testemail"))
.reduce(DefaultObjectReturned, (a1, resultAsPerson) -> resultAsPerson);
```