# find Unique Object matching a property value using Java 7

Tags: java, list, collections, java-7

I have a list of Entity, all entities have unique name, currently to get unique value, I am using MAP of entity name and Entity Object. I dont want to use map just for filter purpose.

I found one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992479/java-8-stream-api-to-find-unique-object-matching-a-property-value), but it usage Java-8.

There is one API in Google Guava com.google.common.collect.Sets.filter(), but it returns Set and in this case I have to get 0th element.

Can anyone suggest better approach.

Comment: I wonder if you had tried anything.
(iterate through the list; break if the name matches.)

Comment: @Mritunja I suppose that he/she wants to a single invocation way or at least a short way as I read "There is one API in Google Guava com.google.common.collect.Sets.filter(), but it returns Set and in this case I have to get 0th element."

Comment: @Mritunjay: For moment stop wondering and read the post again. Stoping wondering, might help to increase concentration and you might understand that I have tried things and then posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Map approach gives you time benefit as lookup time is reduced whereas, but uses memory.

If you are open to Guava try something like:

```
Optional<Entity> result = FluentIterable.from(entityList).firstMatch(new Predicate<Entity>() {
  @Override
  public boolean apply(Entity entity) {
    return entity.getName().equals(input);  //Input can be from variable in function definition
  });
);
```

Something like this, can solve.

Comment: Thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

Try below method:

```
public static Entity findByName(String name, List<Entity> entities) {
        if (entities!= null && name != null) {
            for (Entity e : entities) {
                if (name.equals(e.getName())) {
                    return e;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```